# OneDrive for Business on Windows 7 Won't Install

Tags: windows-7, onedrive-for-business

I have a OneDrive for Business account through school.  I just got a new computer, and I am trying to install the OneDrive for Business app to sync it with my computer.  When I download the installation file and run it, it says, "OneDrive for Business is already installed on your computer."  I have Office 2010, and I am pretty sure the OneDrive app is not on the computer.  Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Try this http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/277757.aspx

Comment: That works, thanks!!  I will point out for anyone else, that you need to scroll down farther to get a good, current link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it up using Windows Installer Cleaner

1. Browse to the [Windows Installer Cleanup Utility (MSICUU2.exe)](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301?siteID=XdSn0e3h3.k-oChVBBeX2Y4gJvcbYiuEhg&wa=wsignin1.0) and click "Run Now" and launch the Fix It.
2. Click "Accept" when prompted and allow the Fix It to run.
3. Select "Detect problems and apply the fixes for me (Recommended)"
4. When prompted, select "Installing"
5. In this instance, I have MS Office 2010 installed.  As such, I was prompted to select "Microsoft Office 2010 Groove MUI (English) 2010" from the list of applications provided.  With other iterations of MS Office, your mileage may vary at this point.
6. On the subsequent step, I was told to select "Yes, try uninstall."
7. You will (hopefully) be notified that the troubleshooting is complete and it will report that it has fixed the issue you selected.  Click "Next" to proceed.
8. I selected "I don't know if the problem has been fixed" on the next screen as instructed by the SharePoint Online Support Engineer and then hit "Next."
   9.I was then instructed to hit "Cancel" on the summary screen at the end.
   10 .Head back into Office 365 and download fresh copy of the OneDrive for Business installer and run it - with hopefully better results that before.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/277757.aspx